# Exitcode 255 on a php script for a CRON task in OVH

Tags: php, cron, ovh

I am working on a PHP project in OVH server. I want to start a script once a day to push an alert.

The script works when i call it manually myself. But when i wait the CRON, i always got the error : exitcode 255 in my logs.

cron.php

```
include('/home/name/path/bdd.php');

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$var = "INSERT INTO `alerts`(`alert_text`, `alert_user`, `alert_link`, `alert_date`) VALUES (:text, :id, :link, NOW())";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($var);

    //Lancement
$insert = $stmt->execute(array(
    ':text' => 'hello',
    ':id' => '2', 
    ':link' => '#'
));
```

OVH logs

```
[2023-12-31 13:42:02] ## OVH ## START - 2023-12-31 13:42:02.401426 executing: /usr/local/php7.3/bin/php /home.XXX/name/path/cron.php 
[2023-12-31 13:42:02] 
[2023-12-31 13:42:02] ## OVH ## END - 2023-12-31 13:42:02.455282 exitcode: 255
```

I tried to change include paths for absolute, to modify my functions or to work procedurally. Nothing change.

Comment: If your code works when manually calling it, then it can't be the code you've posted in the question since you have a syntax error in your INSERT query - you're missing the opening back tick before `alert_date`. What is `bdd.php`? You're including it both before you call `sendAlert()` and again inside. We need more details about your code.

Comment: Yes, just a copy paste error, sorry !

Comment: It's crucial that you post your exact code if you want us to be able to help. We can't detect possible typos, logic issues etc if we don't get to see the actual code. Just copy/paste it into the question "as-is" (with reasonable formatting, ofc).

Comment: I modified the post, but i can't do more for the copy/paste.

Comment: Anything showing in the PHP error logs? If not, the next step is probably adding your own logging. I’d keep it simple, and try to have it log as early as possible in the script. You might need to have a log entry before and after each existing line of code